# Extract text from MS Word (.doc) file in Ruby on Rails web app using Apache POI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, apache-poi, doc

I have gone through APACHE [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) project and found it to be useful for extracting text contents from MS word files. Specifically, there is a feature called [Text Extraction](http://poi.apache.org/text-extraction.html) in POI which does the job effectively. I have also heard about [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) which uses Apache POI internally.

Now, we have a requirement in our Rails web-app to extract the text content from a word `(.doc)` file. What might be the possibilities that we could integrate `Apache POI / Apache Tika` in my web-app to serve my purpose?

If anyone has relevant experience with it, I would love to hear about it  along with the code snippets.

Comment: Why close vote? The question is quite technical and specific. I don't know how to use it in a Rails project, then what would have been a better way to ask it?

Comment: Have you looked at the POI Documentation for Ruby Bindings?  https://poi.apache.org/poi-ruby.html

Comment: The question is very broad and it would be hard to give a definitive answer. Even if everyone will be "sharing one's experiences" it would be hard to choose a single correct answer, as you've provided no objective criteria for doing so. Question shows little research effort - probably you should start with reading the documentation, searching for relevant bindings (as suggested by @NickVeys) and if you'll stumble upon something specific, then you're welcome to ask it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet, since you're not running on a JVM, is to use the [Apache Tika JAXRS server](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS), available from the [Apache Tika download page](http://tika.apache.org/download.html). This provides RESTful interfaces to have Tika extract text (and metadata) from your files.

Because it's a standalone server, you'll only need to launch the JVM once, and it'll then be there and available for each request you send, speeding things up. To get plain text out, send your document to `http://localhost:9998/tika` with a HTTP request header of `Accept: text/plain` and you'll get back the plain text.

You can find more about the available RESTful endpoints of the server on the [Tika Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS), or just by starting the server (`java -jar tika-server-1.X.jar`) and going to `http://localhost:9998/` in your web browser

Comment: Is there any way we could convert the word file content into an exactly alike HTML?

Comment: For fairly similar HTML, set an accept of `text/html` instead of `text/plain`. For exactly the same, you'll need a pet copy of Microsoft Office, and even that's some way off...

Comment: Does it require JRuby? Or is Ruby 1.9 enough?

Comment: It doesn't use ruby at all - Tika runs in a separate Java JVM. You then call it from ruby with your favourite HTTP library